# working with files on "start without debugging"

Tags: c

I'm programming in C, and
I have the following problem:

I use fopen and try to read from a csv file, that is currently storred in the folder of the exe file of the program.

the program works fine in debug mode and release mode, but when I try to run the program in "start without debugging" on visual studio 2008 express edition, the program stops working and windows is showing a message: "***.exe has stopped working. a program caused the program to stop working correctly. windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available".

I've tried running the program on several computers, and it's the same.

another information I can give you is that if I enter the full path of the file (C:....file.csv) - then is works just fine, without any problem.

I know I didn't write any code, but I hope someone will have an idea why this can happend.

thanks is advance.

Answer (score 4):

Your program is not finding the csv file, `fopen()` fails and return a null pointer, you try to use it without checking and your program crashes (just my guess).

Firstly, you must make a check to see if `fopen()` could indeed open your file:

```
FILE* f = fopen("file.csv", "r");
if(f == NULL) {
  /* print some meaningful error */
} else {
  /* use the file */
}
```

Secondly, you may solve the problem by executing your program from the same folder the file is present. I am not a Windows guy, but if you create a link to the ".exe", in its properties may have some configuration called "Working Directory" or something like that, that you may set to the path on where the file can be found.

Every process has a working directory, that is usually the directory from where it was started, though it may be inherited from the parent process and it may be changed programmatically. If you do not specify the full path when loading a file, the process will search for the file in its current working directory.

Comment: To the OP, in addition to this excellent answer, you can also look at argc[0] from main to see what the argument was that invoked your program.  (Like Ivella said, I bet your cwd is different from the executable directory).  Also you might use http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/getenv/ to do some detective work on where you are.  However, I think the "best" solution is to pass in the path as the first argument to your program.  When launching from Visual Studio you should be able to define the arguments to the function.  Twiddle the argument until it matches a correct path.